# Rudin's Proof for Field Axiom 5 in definition of the reals

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading rudin's definition of the reals and in proving the field axiom $a + (-a) = 0$ he states $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta$ is the set of all $p$ such that there exists $r > 0$ for $-p -r \not\in \alpha $.

Then after showing $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ without justification he says if $r \in \alpha$ and $s \in \beta$, then $-s \not \in \alpha$. But isn't that only true for $-s - c$ for some $c > 0$?

What am I missing in my reasoning?

Comment: Which page is this on?

Comment: @Eoin It's on page 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s \in \beta$, then $-s-c \notin \alpha$ for some $c>0$, so that $-s \notin \alpha$ since $-s-c<-s$ and $\alpha$ is a cut and satisfies "If $p \in \alpha$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $q<p$, then $q \in \alpha$" ((II) in definiton of a cut in step 1).

Comment: Ah, I should have seen that. Thank you.